# Python: Finding max of a dictionaries tupled-value

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

How do i find a max of a several tuples compared parallely which is stored in a dictionary.

```
d = {'one':(2,9,6), 'two':(7,2,1), 'three':(1,5,12)}
```

So, tuples (2,9,6),(7,2,1) and (1,5,12) 'zipped' produces the max i.e. (7,9,12).

Please help to advice.

(edited for the numbers confusion)

Comment: If you have the tuples `(1, 2, 3)`, `(4, 5, 6)` and `(2, 3, 8)` which is the max? What about `(1, 2, 3)`, `(4, 5, 6)` and `(7, 0, 0)`?

Comment: By parallely you mean the next element is used as a tie breaker?

Comment: I think you should have provided a better example, `(4,5,6)` is the max of the tuples anyway since `4>3>1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not fully sure from your question what you are looking for, but the zip part made me think that this is what you want:

```
d = {'one':(1,2,3), 'two':(3,2,1), 'three':(4,5,6)}
tuple(max(x) for x in zip(*d.values()))
```

This actually zips the tuples together (first element of first tuple with first element of second tuple and so on) and then finds the max for each of these zipped tuples.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {'one':(2,9,6), 'two':(7,2,1), 'three':(1,5,12)}
tuple(map(max, *d.values()))
```

---

```
$ python -m timeit -s"d = {'one':(2,9,6), 'two':(7,2,1), 'three':(1,5,12)}"\
                     "tuple(map(max, *d.values()))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.08 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s"d = {'one':(2,9,6), 'two':(7,2,1), 'three':(1,5,12)}"\
                     "tuple(max(x) for x in zip(*d.values()))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.1 usec per loop
```